# PHP and regex to cut from begining to new line

Tags: php, regex

I don't have any expirience in regex with php (just some copy/pasting for simple tasks) so I can't 'solve' simple situatio, and I hope that somone can help.

I have a lage files that look like:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
text,text,text,
text,text,tec,etc
```

Now i need in php to write function where passed string with content like this will return me part that I marked here as 'xxx...'
After every 'xxxx...' sequence at file begin, I have as you can see new line (\r\n) and I don't know how to use regex to to cut upper part into another string, so please help.

Answer (score 1):

If the only part of the string separated by two new lines is the header series of  'xxxx' and the following 'text,text,text' lines, you could simply use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Passing a limit of `2` means it will only explode at the first instance of "\n\n", returning an array of at most 2 items:

```
list($header, $body) = explode("\n\n", $file_contents, 2);
```

Comment: Small problem is that in MOST files it is only new line, but in some there few other down in file, anycase I need just to cut from beginning to FIRST NEW line, after that I don't need anything, so this will work, but is there better way to match just first new line ? anycase thanks for answer!

Comment: @Sam You can add a limit of 2 to the `explode`, which insures that all double-newlines after the first are ignored. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd skip the regex.

```
$eol = strpos($s, "\r\n");
$header = substr($s, 0, $eol);
$rest = substr($s, $eol + 2);
```